# theoritical results Fluid structure interaction

Tags: functional-analysis

I am currently conducting complex simulation involving deformation of a solid object ( which is a surface, or a shell using the vocabulary of structural mechanics) and some fluid discretized using a particle method ( namely SPH). I am used to look at theoritical results to understand a bit a behavior of the solutions ( existence, unicity, rate of convergence, potential numerical issues, ...) but for this case I could not find anything.

Is anyone aware of some literature on the topic ?

Thanks,

Quentin